# T-SQL equivalent of IEnumerable.Zip()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a T-SQL stored procedure, when supplied with two tables each of which has the same number of rows, how can I pair-wise match the rows based on row order rather than a join criteria?

Basically, an equivalent of .NET's IEnumerable.Zip() method?

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

**Background**

The purpose of the stored procedure is to act as an integration adapter between two other applications. I do not control the source code for either application.

The "client" application contains extensibility objects which can be *configured* to invoke a stored procedure in an SQL Server database. The configuration options for the extensibility point allow me to name a stored procedure which will be invoked, and provide a *statically configured* list of named parameters and their associated values, which will be passed to the stored procedure. Only scalar parameters are supported, not table-valued parameters.

The stored procedure needs to collect data from the "server" application (which is exposed through an OLE-DB provider) and transform it into a suitable result set for consumption by the client application.

For maintenance reasons, I want to avoid storing any *configuration* in the adapter database. I want to write generic, flexible logic in the stored procedure, and pass all necessary configuration information as parameters to that stored procedure.

The configuration information that's needed for the stored procedure is, essentially, equivalent to the following table variable schema:

```
DECLARE @TableOfServerQueryParameterValues AS TABLE (
    tag NVARCHAR(50),
    filterexpr NVARCHAR(500)
)
```

This table can then be used as the left-hand side of `JOIN` and `CROSS APPLY` queries in the stored proc which are run against the "server" application interfaces.

The problem I encountered is that I did not know of any way of passing a table of parameter info from the client application, because its extensibility points only include scalar parameter support.

So, I thought I would pass two scalar parameters. One would be a comma-separated list of `tag` values. The other would be a comma-separated list of `filterexpr` values.

Inside the stored proc, it's easy to use `STRING_SPLIT` to convert each of those parameters into a single-column table. But then I needed to match the two columns together into a two-column table, which I could then use as the basis for `INNER JOIN` or `CROSS APPLY` to query the server application.

The best solution I've come up with so far is selecting each table into a table variable and use the ROW_NUMBER() function to assign a row number, and then join the two tables together by matching on the extra ROW_NUMBER column. Is there an easier way to do it than that? It would be nice not to have to declare all the columns in the table variables.

Comment: There is no row order in a table. It is an important difference to `IEnumerable` that does have an order. When using `row_number` you still have to provide `order by`. You don't have to put the `row_number`'ed results into a temporary table, you can use a subquery.

Comment: Your current approach with `row_number()` feels best to me.  You could switch table variables for common table expressions (CTEs) or simply subqueries to get everything in one statement.

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation from downvoters why this question is inappropriate for StackOverflow. Surely it's not unreasonable for someone with a background in one type of programming to ask how to achieve similar results in a different technology?

Comment: Out of interest, why are people downvoting this?  The question seems clear & on topic.  @Hydrargyrum is saying "is there a better way than `row_number()`, and it appears the answer's likely "no"; but that doesn't mean the question's bad.

Comment: I didnt downvote, but questions like this with no table description, no example TSQL just have a smell. Some people drive-by downvote without seeking the interesting question inside a bit of a wishy-washy one.

Comment: @Hydrargyrum No SQL, no table schema, no data, how can anyone answer? As for `STRING_SPLIT` on *strings* - don't please. Use table valued parameters. Better yet, if you have a lot of data, use staging tables.

Comment: The application calling this stored procedure doesn't have any way to pass table-valued parameters. Only scalars. If I could pass table-valued parameters I wouldn't need to match the parameters to each other at all. Good advice, though.

Comment: @Hydrargyrum you are trying to cover up a bug - sendint a *single record's* data through separate string lists. If you did use TVPs you wouldn't have to split strings or try to recombine them to original records. Use JSON. Use XML. Anything that allows you to pass each record without splitting it to unrelated strings

Comment: @Hydrargyrum why aren't you using an ORM anyway to do this?

Comment: Because I don't own the application source code. It does have extensibility mechanisms which include calling stored procs (and passing scalar parameters to those stored procs). I'm integrating it with an external system, and what I have full control over is the stored procedures in the interface. The XML suggestion seems like a good way to pass everything required in a single parameter, I'll look into that.

Comment: Can you give a bit more background on where these strings are coming from / what code's calling this stored procedure / what pieces you have control over?  As @PanagiotisKanavos suggests there are likely better ways; though obviously any external constraints will limit what's possible.

Comment: @Hydrargyrum you'll have to be *specific*. Do you mean that the other application can only send string lists? Can't it format them somehow? How can it generate the string lists anyway? Generating a partial JSON string is *easy* if you can specify the format string, record/field separators, eg `:` and `,`. The stored procedure would only have to perform some replacements to generate a valid JSON string

Comment: @Hydrargyrum using XML is the same as JSON - once you have a valid XML/JSon string you can use the native functions to query nodes, values, attributes etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion of using `row_number` seems sound.
Instead of table variables you can use subqueries or CTEs; there should be little difference overall, though avoiding the table variable reduces the number of passes you need to make & avoids the additional code to maintain.

```
select a.*, b.* --specify whatever columns you want to return
from (
    select *
    , row_number() over (order by someArbitraryColumnPreferablyYourClusteredIndex) r
    from TableA
) a
full outer join --use a full outer if your have different numbers of rows in the tables & want 
                --results from the larger table with nulls from the smaller for the bonus rows
                --otherwise use an inner join to only get matches for both tables
(
    select *
    , row_number() over (order by someArbitraryColumnPreferablyYourClusteredIndex) r
    from TableA
) b
on b.r = a.r
```

---

**Update**

Regarding @PanagiotisKanavos's comment on passing structured data, here's a simple example of how you could convert a value passed as an xml type to table data:

```
declare @tableA xml = '<TableA>
<row><col1>x</col1><col2>Anne</col2><col3>Droid</col3></row>
<row><col1>y</col1><col2>Si</col2><col3>Borg</col3></row>
<row><col1>z</col1><col2>Roe</col2><col3>Bott</col3></row>
</TableA>'

select row_number() over (order by aRow) r
, x.aRow.value('(./col1/text())[1]' , 'nvarchar(32)') Code
, x.aRow.value('(./col2/text())[1]' , 'nvarchar(32)') GivenName
, x.aRow.value('(./col3/text())[1]' , 'nvarchar(32)') Surname
from @tableA.nodes('/*/*') x(aRow)
```

You may get a performance boost over the above by using the following.  This creates a dummy column allowing us to do an `order by` where we don't care about the order.  This should be faster than the above as ordering by 1 will be simpler than sorting based on the xml type.

```
select row_number() over (order by ignoreMe) r
, x.aRow.value('(./col1/text())[1]' , 'nvarchar(32)') Code
, x.aRow.value('(./col2/text())[1]' , 'nvarchar(32)') GivenName
, x.aRow.value('(./col3/text())[1]' , 'nvarchar(32)') Surname
from @tableA.nodes('/*/*') x(aRow)
cross join (select 1) a(ignoreMe)
```

If you do care about the order, you can order by the data's fields, as such:

```
select row_number() over (order by x.aRow.value('(./col1/text())[1]' , 'nvarchar(32)') ) r
, x.aRow.value('(./col1/text())[1]' , 'nvarchar(32)') Code
, x.aRow.value('(./col2/text())[1]' , 'nvarchar(32)') GivenName
, x.aRow.value('(./col3/text())[1]' , 'nvarchar(32)') Surname
from @tableA.nodes('/*/*') x(aRow)
```

Comment: Check the OP's comments. The string lists contain record attributes broken apart. The OP is trying to `Zip` them together again. Far, far better to *not* break them apart, eg by sending thema as JSON or XML. A TVP that contains all attributes would be even better but the OP says this isn't possible for some reason

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos; didn't see that modification before posting.

Comment: This answer does solve the problem of how to most simply implement `IEnumerable.Zip()`-like semantics in T-SQL, which was the original question. I'll do some reading on how to use the XML/JSON query constructs to treat a string parameter like a table, which might solve the bigger picture problem in a more elegant way.

Comment: FYI: Updated to include the additional info on using XML types (I've not yet played with JSON as that's only available as of SQL 2016; but it looks pretty straightforward: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dataplatforminsider/2016/01/05/json-in-sql-server-2016-part-1-of-4/).  Good luck.

Comment: This might be better as a recursive CTE, this way you specify the sub-select once. Also, you can make it a hash join with maxdop set to control the number of hash tables used to build the data streams.